# Fire event on database datetime field

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, events

I have table in the database like this:

[image: test]

What is the best way to implement trigger of event somewhere (in SQL server database or `c#` application) on time of event field in table.

Edit:

Traditionally I would have done something like this:

```
while(true)
{
  DataTable tbl = getRows("select * from table where event=" + DateTime.now());
  if(tbl.rows.Count()>0)
   {
     //do some thing
   }
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?
(I don't want periodically check Database)

Comment: What kind of condition? What is your goal? Is it about a database-operation or execution of code in C#? You should provide some details of what exactly you want to do.

Comment: thanks. imagine i want send reminder SMS to client exactly on date and time entered in event field. no matter this event happen in c# or Database  i can handle both.

Comment: Do you know how to access the database from C#?

Comment: yes i know how to access the database from C#

Comment: That edit isnt bad ;). Now its a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I would go like this:

```
public class Notify
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}

public Timer tData = new Timer();
public List<Notify> Notifications = new List<Notify>();

public void Main()
{
    // 5 minutes
    tData.Interval = 1000;
    tData.Tick += new EventHandler(CheckEvents);
}

public void GetAllEvents()
{
    DataTable results = new DataTable();
    /* results = YourDatabase(Select id, name, event FROM...); */

    Notifications.Clear();

    foreach(DataRow row in results.Rows)
    {
        Notifications.Add
        (
            new Notify
            {
                ID = int.Parse(row[0].ToString()),
                Name = row[1].ToString(),
                Time = DateTime.Parse(row[2].ToString())
            }
        );
    }
}

public void CheckEvents(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IEnumerable<Notify> eventsElapsed = Notifications.Where(notify => notify.Time == DateTime.Now);

    foreach(Notify notify in eventsElapsed)
    {
        // Send your sms
        var id = notify.ID;
        var name = notify.Name;
        var time = notify.Time;
    }
}
```

**To-Do's:**

- Care for the correct format when getting the `DateTime` out of your database. It might look different.
- You would have to think about how to get new events. I would do it either by a button-click or by setting up another timer with an interval of something around 5-10 minutes. You can just call `GetAllEvents()`.

*I dont think you are inserting new events that will have their time in between the next 30 seconds.*

---

**Another *more advanced* way:**

You could also setup 2 apps for this.

***First app:***

- Get all Events from Database
- Optionally create an UI that allows to filter which events should be get
- Link every event to [Scheduled Tasks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) with start arguments like `secondApp.exe "2016-06-26 10:13:56"`.

***Second app:***

- On startup, fetch the passed arguments and send the SMS.

If your table has lots of data, its not bad to split the time consuming process of hooking up events (1st app) from the simple process of sending out a SMS (2nd app).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your second way is more efficient. because i don't want periodically check database I can create scheduled Task when new event inserted in database.What do you think?

Comment: @M.SadeghAzarkaman You have to check if there is a new entry for yourself. There is no trigger that will fire in C# without asking the database with a `SELECT`. So it doesnt matter if you pick the first or second solution. You will have to press a button or go with a timer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mess with `trigger`s at the database for this purpose.

In C# you write the code for your logic - the thing you need to be done. Next designate an object which stores the input parameters + the time to start this logic. E.g. in SMS system we need the subscriber number, the message and the time of sending.

At your system startup (for example) you read the data to obtain the times. Start some threads and make them wait (`Sleep`) as long as needed, then execute the target method. Something like this:

```
class SmsDetails
{
    public string Subscriber { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public DateTime SendOn { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlDataReader schedule = null; // Initialize the reader as appropriate.

        while (schedule.Read())
        {
            var det = new SmsDetails();
            //.
            //.
            //.
            det.SendOn = schedule.GetDateTime(2);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ScheduleSending, det);
        }

    }

    static void ScheduleSending(object Details)
    {
        var smsd = Details as SmsDetails;

        if (smsd.SendOn > DateTime.Now)
        {
            var waitInterval = DateTime.Now - smsd.SendOn;
            Thread.Sleep(waitInterval);
            SendSms(smsd.Subscriber, smsd.Message);
        }
    }

    static void SendSms(string PhoneNumber, string Message)
    {
        // Send it out
    }
}
```

Of course this is not the complete code for such a solution but I hope you get the idea. You need to take care to signal (in the DB?) if the message was sent. You can also employ wait handles to interrupt the threads from the calling code. 
Depending on the volume of the records in the reader you may want to poll the DB for the message about to be send in the next 1, 6, 12 and so on. E.g. if you need to dispatch 10000 messages over the next 3 days don't schedule them now. Having too many threads can degrade the performance.